# Changing image in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I am wanting advice on 'how' to change images in a flutter app on the fly.  Consider a passport stamp.

The user would select from a list of travel modes (say 6 to choose from).  Plane, ship, Bus, Train, etc.

The user would pick a shape from a list (say 10 to choose from).  The shape would be a square, or circle, rectangle on so on.

Once the user selects the shape, it would be displayed in the App.  Assume travel mode selected is Plane and the shape selected is  a circle (refer to as outer image).

The App then displays an image of a circle, with image of the Plane in the middle of the circle (refer to as inner image), but smaller.  This shape would be displayed in black (default).

The user would then pick a colour from a list (say 10 to choose from).  Black, Red, Blue, Green etc.

As the user selects the colour, the displayed shape would also change colour (both the outer image and the inner image).

Naturally, I could have a stored image of the 10 shapes x 10 colour variations x 6 colour variations, but thats 600 images.  Must be an easier way.

As selections are changed, the resulting displayed image would aslo change.  The user could change the outer image, from circle to square, and/or change the travel mode from plane to ship, and/or the colour from black to red.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the 600 images. use the custom painter widget. and paint the shape and color.
so in this case you only need to save the travel modes images in the assets

make the code like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Define variables to store user selections
  String travelMode = "Plane";
  String selectedShape = "Circle";
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Passport Stamp')),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // UI elements for user selections (Dropdowns, Radios, etc.)
              // Update the selected variables based on user input
              
              // CustomPaint widget to display the dynamic image
              CustomPaint(
                size: Size(200, 200), // Adjust size as needed
                painter: MyPainter(
                  travelMode: travelMode,
                  shape: selectedShape,
                  color: selectedColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final String travelMode;
  final String shape;
  final Color color;

  MyPainter({
    required this.travelMode,
    required this.shape,
    required this.color,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Paint the background with the selected color
    final backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromPoints(Offset.zero, size.bottomRight(Offset.zero)), backgroundPaint);

    // Calculate the radius for the shape (circle in this case)
    final radius = size.shortestSide / 2;

    // Calculate the center point
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // Paint the shape (circle, square, etc.) with a border
    final shapePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.transparent // Set the border color to transparent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke // Use stroke to draw the border
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0; // Adjust border width as needed

    if (shape == "Circle") {
      canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, shapePaint);
    } else if (shape == "Square") {
      final squareRect = Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2);
      canvas.drawRect(squareRect, shapePaint);
    }

    // Load and draw the image (plane) in the center
    final image = Image.asset("assets/$travelMode.png"); // Replace with your image asset path
    final imageRect = Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2);

    paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: imageRect,
      image: image.image,
      fit: BoxFit.contain, // Adjust the fit as needed
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true; // Return true to always repaint when user selections change
  }
}
```